# Controlling Auto Rotation with toggle?

Tags: android, orientation, settings

I want to create a toggle button through which I can enable/disable auto rotation. I've tried this:

```
public void arclick(View view) {
        if (arclick.isChecked())
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, 90);
        else
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, 0);
    }
```

But it's not working actually. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!!
P.S: The selected orientation should be applied to whole operating system and not just in the app.

Comment: have you declared <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission> in manifest?

Comment: Yeah I added permission. @abhishesh

Comment: When I used the code from the first answer of the post my phone started to restart again and again, it's insane! It was a loop!!! I reinstalled my stock rom, now I've lost my all SMS and other stuff. I don't know how this happened!!!

Comment: As per developer site : "Default screen rotation when no other policy applies. When ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION is zero and no on-screen Activity expresses a preference, this rotation value will be used."
write value of ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION to zero first

Comment: Dude, can you show me an example? I'll accept your answer sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per developer docs :

> USER_ROTATION :
>   Default screen rotation when no other policy applies. When ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION is zero and no on-screen Activity expresses a preference, this rotation value will be used. Must be one of the Surface rotation constants.

Before using USER_ROTATION, you need to set ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION to 0.
Like :

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
android.provider.Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0); 
if (arclick.isChecked())
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, Surface.ROTATION_90);
else
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, Surface.ROTATION_0);
```

And dont use value 90, use Surface.ROTATION_90(whose value is 1 not 90).

And if you want to disable rotation feature, use :

```
if(disable)
   android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
   android.provider.Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0); 
else //enable
   android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
   android.provider.Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 1);
```